# reading accelerometer value

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android development, and just know started to learn how to use the sensors.

I started reading about the sensors in the the developers.android site, and came across [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) article.

it says there that in order to get the real acceleration you should apply  a `high pass filter`, because the sensor reads also the gravity force.

*my question is:* why not just subtract the gravity force (g) from the value?

Comment: In you question you use the word subscribe.  Do you mean subtract instead as in "subtract the gravity force (g) from the value?"

Comment: @RichardChambers sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the actual sensed gravity depend on the angle of your device to the vertical.

A high pass will filter constants (and slow movements)

[What are High-Pass and Low-Pass Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530/what-are-high-pass-and-low-pass-filters) containing links to various resources.