# Math Library for peaks finding

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, max

Is there any free math library for peaks/valley finding in 2D array? I can write a simple one checking the slope in two consecutive steps, but I need something more advanced, like tolerance to small noise or less tolerance in the abcicess (if the peaks are placed very close to each other).

Comment: You could implement a [low pass filter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/82372/21727).

Answer (score 1):

You make your naive peak finding algorithm more robust by first applying a moving average filter to your data. That will smooth out any noise and other very local features.